# Web application gets "HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized" error on Microsoft Edge

Tags: web-applications, microsoft-edge

When I run the web application locally with IE I have no problem but with Edge or Chrome, it keeps asking for user name and password and it does not go through. It seems like the Windows authentication doesn't go through although I am using the correct credentials. When I cancel the Sign in box I get the Error 401.2
My other colleague doesn't have the same issue and he can run with Edge. please help!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if it is a local web application, Chromium Edge should follow relvant settings in `Internet Options`. Please check the following configuration to Enable Integrated Windows Authentication:

1. Type `Internet Options` in windows search and press key `Enter`.
2. Select the `Advanced` tab.
3. Scroll down to the `Security` section until you see option **Enable Integrated Windows Authentication**. Select the box next to this field to enable.
4. Select the `Security` tab.
5. Select `Local Intranet` and select the `Custom Level` or `Advanced` button.
6. Scroll down to `User Authentication` > `Logon`.
7. Checked the `Automatic logon with current user name and password` option.
8. In the `Security` tab, select `Local Intranet` option and click the `Sites` button.
9. Click the `Advanced` button, then, add your website to the zone.
10. Close the window and apply the configuration.

For more details, just refer to [this doc](https://textslashplain.com/2020/01/30/security-zones-in-edge/).

Comment: I was only able to do the first three steps you mentioned and the option was already enabled. Unfortunately I am not the Admin of my machine and I can't check the other steps you mentioned.

Comment: If this is the case, did you ask the relevant management to configure it?